# Слово "бесталанный"

Tags: этимология

Погуглив, я узнал, что у слово [**бесталанный** *(корень -талан-)*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)  не синоним слову [**талант** (корень *-талант-*)](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82), когда оно употреблено в значении *"несчастный, неудачливый, обездоленный"*, но когда употреблено в значении *"бездарный"*, то связано с *"талантом"* (пометка внизу страницы о слове [*бесталанный*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)). Так вот, в этом самом случае, когда эти два слова связаны, являются ли они однокоренными? Если да, то куда делать буква *"т"*, ведь слова *"бесталантный"* не существует.

Comment: Ну... Вообще-то слово "бесталантный" имеется в языке (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/141847/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9). Устаревающее, правда. *Забудем о группе **бесталантных** юношей из Лито и Пролеткультов; не их вина, что этих юнцов посадили на гору: «сиди, как Бог, и вешай»* (В. Г. Шершеневич. 2×2=5 (1920)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Талант* и *талан* - это паронимы (близкие по звучанию и написанию, но разные по значению и происхождению).
*Талант* - одаренность от природы, *талан* - судьба.

Answer (score 5):

> слово бесталанный (корень -талан-) не синоним слову талант

Даже не антоним.

В чем вопрос?

I тала́нт
I, род. п. -а "мера веса", Нов. зав., Матф. 25, 15 и сл. (у Лескова и др.), русск.-цслав., ст.-слав. таланътъ τάλαντον (Зогр., Мар., Остром.). Из греч. τάλαντον "весы; денежно-расчетная единица" от ταλαντ- "несущий"; см. Фасмер, Гр.-сл. эт. 199; ИОРЯС 12, 2, 280; Сольмсен, IFAnz. 32, 87; Кречмер, Glotta 3, 266 и сл.

II тала́нт
II. Вероятно, под влиянием формы тала́нт I через франц. talent "талант, одаренность" от лат. talentum из греч. τάλαντον; см. Горяев, ЭС 360; Клюге-Гётце 609 и сл.

(Фасмер)

Даже если греческий (вернее - праиндоевропейский) корень и один, дальше слова шли разными путями, в русский попали из разных языков. Далеко все лингвисты признаЮт такие слова родственными **в русском**, но это отдельный разговор.
Конечное t пропало во французском.

Comment: а каким образом, кто скажет...  в русский,  кто внедрением занимался, конкретно?

  от лености.
короче, та лента---в латинском от лености, от ленты нашей, по лености не связать, не развязать. Как и галстук ныне.... тянуто все, читайте Фоменко с Носовским, и ищите смысл в корнях слов, Латынь по большей части "ваша конкатенация" всех языков, которые монахи стали пользовать от своей ущербности и мании величия.

Answer (score 2):

Слово *"талан"* есть в украинском языке. Правда оно не особо часто употребляется. Могу предположить, что не всякий украинец (или не во всяком регионе) знает значение этого слова. А значит оно *судьба*, *удача*.

Устойчивые выражения (думаю, большинству украинцев известные ) : "Нема талану", "Не поталанило" (т.е. не везёт, не повезло). Самостоятельно это слово "талан", как мне кажется, употребляется редко. По крайней мере, в Центральной Украине в разговорной речи (кроме тех выражений, что выше) мне не приходилось слышать.

Если это уместно на русскоязычном форуме, могу привести пример стихов с этим словом. С моим дословным переводом.

**Леся Украинка. «О, знаю я, багато ще промчить…»** ("О, знаю я, много ещё промчится..")
Отрывок.

```
Не раз мене обгорне, мов туман,
Страшного розпачу отрутнеє дихання,
Тяжке безвір’я в себе, в свій **талан**
І в те, що у людей на світі є призвання.
```

---

```
Не раз меня окутает, словно туман,
Страшного отчаяния ядовитое дыхание,
Тяжёлое безверие в себя, в свою удачу,
И в то, что у людей на свете есть призвание.
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что в этом стихотворении "талан" не равно "талант"? По смыслу вроде подходит!

Comment: Да, по смыслу подходит. Когда написал сообщение на этот форум, то позже и сам задумался. Но слово "талант" (в смысле одарённости) по-украински так и пишется "талант". Такое шоу есть, популярное на Украине, "Україна має таланти". "Украина имеет таланты". Вот в слове "талантливый", укр. "талановитий", буква "т" выпадает.

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемая Nantey, слово доля происходит от глагола делить, т.е. к талану и таланту вообще не имеет отношения. К сожалению, Вы впадаете в весьма распространенный грех - т.н. народную этимологию. Про атомный реактор люди знают, что его устройство понятно только специалистам, а про язык, думают, что это просто: посмотри, что на что похоже - и толкуй себе. А лингвистика - это наука, притом довольно точная. И совсем не такая доступная, как может показаться со стороны. Когда-то малообразованные люди вместо пиджак говорили спинжак - дескать, он спину прикрывает. Им простительно - не было возможности учится. И сейчас не стыдно чего-то не знать, но отдавать себе отчет, что ты знаешь, а что нет, уважать профессионалов - это, мне кажется, правильно для человека любой профессии в наше просвещенное время.
Еще маленькое замечание. Удар и дар тоже не "родственники". Удар - это от драть, там же раздор и т.п. А дар - это от дать.

Answer (score 0):

ТАЛАН (счастье). Заимств. в XVII в. из тюркск. яз., где талан "счастье" < "добыча" (буквально — "награбленное") — производное от тала- "грабить, хватать". См. бесталанный.
Этимологический словарь, 2004

А далее адресую к ответу begemothus'а и inna.

> Вот это мне как раз и не очень понятно... Ну допустим, в русский могло попасть в XVII веке, а во французский-то как? В латынь?

Похоже, Вы совсем не поняли...
ТАЛАН - ныне малоупотребительное слово, означающее *счастье,доля,судьба*(от него и произошло Ваше БЕСТАЛАННЫЙ) зимствовано примерно в XVII столетии (скорее всего ранее-*Варяг-91*) из тюркского, который служил *койне*(а это посмотрите сами в словаре) на обширнейшей территории, в которую входила и Русь,Белая, Черная и Малая,соответственно, образованные люди из числа торговцев, государевых мужей, посредников, просто грамотеев, без услуг которых тогда  было не прожить, служили проводниками, которые переносили отдельные слова и устойчивые выражения из одного народа в другой(из языка в язык).Некоторые из слов и выражений закреплялись в новом языке, распространялись, проибретая иногда несколько иной смысл или окраску.

В отношении слова ТАЛАНТ подобные процессы происходили намного ранее, когда задолго до РХ древнегреческий язык являлся *койне* для огромной земли, *ойкумены*, куда впоследствии вошла территория Древнего Рима, колоссального многонационального государства с государственным латинским языком, названным так по имени племени латинов, населявшиго тогда вместе с другими племенами Аппенинский полуостров. А латинский язык, мало того что был *койне* Европы в послегреческий период и  еще очень долго, почти до новейших времен был языком ученых всего мира, стал в позднем средневековье основой, на которой сформировались множество европейских языков(*романские языки*, от *Рома* - Рим), в том числе и французский язык.

А теперь еще раз прочтите все ответы - может быть станет понятнее.

Comment: Вот это мне как раз и не очень понятно...
Ну допустим, а русский могдо попасть в XVII веке, а во французский-то как? В латынь?

Что это за словарь? Опять Шанский, что ли? Или Тихонов?

Answer (score 0):

Для этимологической  правильности  понимания  внутренней  формы  слова  с
функциональной  реальностью  его  существования  в  языке советую прочитать статью доктора филологических наук Романова Д.А. https://russkayarech.ru/ru/archive/2011-6/103-109 Вот ссылка.

Comment: ответ бессодержательный.

Answer (score -2):

Очень похоже,что тюркский вариант наиболее приемлем.БЕС=без,корень-ТАЛАН.Учитывая чередование звонкий-глухой в савянотюркском обороте речи:(1-пер=бир,5-пешт=биш),то это слово могло звучать,как ДОЛАНЬ=доля,аналог-обездоленный.,но в русском языке есть слова похожие по значению(бестолочь,обездол,толк,толмач)Здесь корень-тал,тол,дал,что вероятно и означало в древности-дар,одарение,ударение.,ср.дар=удар,толк=толкнул,дал=потдал.

Comment: Какие-то глупости, имхо. Толмач - вполне явственно означает "переводчик" . Пришло из венгерского, а изначальнр вероятно тюркское.  Вряд ли наоборот.

Comment: Участник @Nantey обладает большой смелостью в своих предположениях. Даже, я бы сказала, излишней.

Comment: Ну и я согласна свами,что из тюркского.Но слово-словом,а корень его ТАЛ...,ПРОСТО предположила,что аналог в русском ему-ДОЛ,и немного поразмышляла над древним его значением.

Comment: Несколько странный способ рассуждений для этимологии. Дело же не в том, что на что  похоже, а как было на самом деле.

Comment: Т.е было на самом деле ровно так,как думаете вы???Есть в мире 2 мнения для вас:1-ваше и правильное,2-чужое,тупое и неправильное...так что-ли??